# tmux powerline symbols not rendering properly despite having proper fonts installed

Tags: bash, tmux, powerline

I am using [this tmux configuration](https://github.com/gpakosz/.tmux). It works fine, except the powerline symbols are not rendered. I have installed the correct fonts, and am using them in the terminal. From the docs:

> I installed Powerline and/or (patched) fonts but can't see Powerline
> symbols.
>
> First, you don't need to install Powerline. You only need fonts
> patched with Powerline symbols or the standalone PowerlineSymbols.otf
> font. Then make sure your ~/.tmux.conf.local copy uses the right code
> points for tmux_conf_theme_left_separator_XXX values.

I checked the config file and tried rendering the symbols, and they all work fine.
[image: unicode rendering properly]

And viewing `~/.tmux.conf.local` shows that these unicode characters are consistent:

[image: .tmux.conf.local output]

So I have installed the right fonts, am using the right fonts in my terminal, can render the right glyphs (when using Python). But it doesn't display in the powerline.

What can I try to do to make the symbols render correctly?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, the default terminal, and tmux.

Answer (score 25):

I had trouble with this too while using the ariline in vim and I found an answer that worked for me. Forgot the original source so cant link it.

**Use `tmux -u`**

Comment: `-u`:    Write UTF-8 output to the terminal even if the first environment variable of LC_ALL, LC_CTYPE, or LANG that is set does not contain "UTF-8" or "UTF8".

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKGzE.png)

change the settings in your ~/.tmux.conf.local as shown to enable using powerline fonts
basically the below code tries to turn on powerline font as seperator while the above four lines doesn't use it

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `tmux -u` you could make sure that the locale is configured correctly.

try

`$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`

and select something with UTF-8.
logout, back in and tmux should just work.

verify in tmux or with `echo $LANG`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).